# NextJS prerender error when rendering sitemap.xml

Tags: next.js, sitemap, next.js13, sitemap.xml

I'm building myself a simple markdown based blog and everything worked fine under developer environment but when it comes to build my project with the command `npm run build`, it gives me pre-rendering failed error.

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/sitemap.xml". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
YAMLException: can not read a block mapping entry; a multiline key may not be an implicit key at line 5, column 1:

    ^
    at generateError (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:7999:12)
    at throwError (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:8002:11)
    at readBlockMapping (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:8631:17)
    at composeNode (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:8834:84)
    at readDocument (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:8958:5)
    at loadDocuments (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:9003:9)
    at load (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:9021:21)
    at Object.safeLoad (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:9039:12)
    at module.exports (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:6953:19)
    at parseMatter (/Users/batuhan/Git/blog-site/.next/server/chunks/325.js:6702:21)
- info Generating static pages (8/8)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /sitemap.xml/route: /sitemap.xml
```

Even tho it gives me errors while building for production, the sitemap works perfectly fine under dev mode. Here is my sitemap.js file:

```
import { getPostMetadata } from "@/libs/getPostMetadata"
import { getPageMetadata } from "@/libs/getPageMetadata";
import { readConfig } from "@/libs/readConfig";

const config = readConfig();

export default async function sitemap() {
    const siteURL = config.siteURL
    const postMeta = await getPostMetadata();
    const postMetadata = postMeta.map((post) => {
        return {
            url: `${siteURL}/blog/${post.slug}`,
            lastModified: post.date
        }
    });

    const pageMeta = getPageMetadata();
    const pageMetadata = pageMeta.map((page) => {
        return {
            url: `${siteURL}/${page.slug}`,
            lastModified: new Date()
        }
    })

    return [
        {
            url: siteURL,
            lastModified: new Date(),
        },
        {
            url: `${siteURL}/about`
        },
        ...pageMetadata,
        ...postMetadata
    ]
}
```

As a fix I tried to remove the pageMetadata and postMetadata from it just in case but the result was same, works under dev mode but doesn't on production build.

##### Here is the sitemap.xml file I want to generate which generates perfectly fine under dev mode

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.984Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/about</loc>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/about</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.984Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/ack</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.984Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blogroll</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.984Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/links</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.984Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/main</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.984Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2022-06-15-creating-a-new-blog-site-how-i-created-it</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2022-06-16-configuring-jekyll</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2022-06-23-im-using-an-hackintosh-for-6-months-now-what</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2022-11-30-here-goes-the-november-2022</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2022-12-31-here-comes-the-2023-what-do-i-expect</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-01-20-using-an-iphone-6-plus-as-a-secondary-phone-in-2023</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-01-22-beginning-of-the-100daystooffload</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-01-23-finally-https</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-01-26-its-time-for-personal-blogs-to-make-a-comeback</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-01-27-adding-rss-feeds-from-other-blogs-to-end-of-my-posts</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-02-23-im-back-on-blogging</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-03-02-my-messed-up-mind</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-03-09-im-on-diffblog-now</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-03-21-10th-post-of-100daystooffload</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-03-21-migrating-server-went-wrong</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-04-23-i-created-a-backup-site</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-01-iphone-7-plus-review-is-it-still-usable-in-2023</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-01-the-page-you-currently-in</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-05-today-is-6-may-2023</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-08-recreating-optiplex-server</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-09-it-was-firewall</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-10-i-switched-to-obsidian</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-22-I-hate-ubuntu-and-its-my-daily-driver-now</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-05-30-personal-blogs-should-be-simple</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-06-02-here-goes-my-highschool-life</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-06-23-I-m-sorry-but-I-m-not-going</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-06-28-we-already-have-mastodon</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-07-08-leaving-my-paid</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-08-01-25th-post</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-08-01-26th-post</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-08-03-27th-post</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
<url>
<loc>www.thebatuhansnetwork.xyz/blog/2023-08-08-I-just-rewrite-my-blog</loc>
<lastmod>2023-08-25T15:49:10.983Z</lastmod>
</url>
</urlset>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please share the sitemap.xml file here?
Or tryout this GitHub issue if it fixes for you
https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/1156

Comment: I've updated my question and added the one that's generated at dev mode. @Bhumit070

Answer (score -1):

Ok guys I found the problem. The config file I used had a problem on one of it's elements and even tho it's won't used on sitemap.xml it still reported as a problem at sitemap.xml. Fixing that line on my config.yml file fixed the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).